# Delete Json data with generated ID

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, cordova

how can i remove a Array from a JSON with a generated ID.

So i have a JSON Like:

```
{
    "Artikel":[
        { "id:1, artikelnr": "23453345", "anzahl": 22},
        { "id:2, artikelnr": "asd323", "anzahl": 2223},
        { "id:5, artikelnr": "dfsdf3893", "anzahl": 72},
        { "id:6, artikelnr": "asdikr38", "anzahl": 86},
        { "id:9, artikelnr": "2sad34533asd45", "anzahl": 10}
    ]
}
```

and i like to remove the json for example with the id 6, then the JSON should look like:

```
{
     "Artikel":[
         { "id:1, artikelnr": "23453345", "anzahl": 22},
         { "id:2, artikelnr": "asd323", "anzahl": 2223},
         { "id:5, artikelnr": "dfsdf3893", "anzahl": 72},
         { "id:9, artikelnr": "2sad34533asd45", "anzahl": 10}
     ]
}
```

how can i make this?

Comment: You should restructure it first. Having `id:9, artikelnr` as a property name is not very useful.

Comment: @DanielKreiner is it your keys of object? `"id:2, artikelnr":`? maybe it looks like this? `"id":5, "artikelnr":dfsdf3893`

Answer (score 0):

You can map over each object, split the key and check if id:6 exists:

```js
const obj = { Artikel: [{ "id:1, artikelnr": "23453345", anzahl: 22 }, { "id:2, artikelnr": "asd323", anzahl: 2223 }, { "id:5, artikelnr": "dfsdf3893", anzahl: 72 }, { "id:6, artikelnr": "asdikr38", anzahl: 86 }, { "id:9, artikelnr": "2sad34533asd45", anzahl: 10 }] };

obj.Artikel = obj.Artikel.filter(o => Object.keys(o).every(i => i.split(', ')[0] !== 'id:6'))
console.log(obj)
```

You could even go as far as splitting again to use a blacklist:

```js
const obj = { Artikel: [{ "id:1, artikelnr": "23453345", anzahl: 22 }, { "id:2, artikelnr": "asd323", anzahl: 2223 }, { "id:5, artikelnr": "dfsdf3893", anzahl: 72 }, { "id:6, artikelnr": "asdikr38", anzahl: 86 }, { "id:9, artikelnr": "2sad34533asd45", anzahl: 10 }] };

const blacklist = [1, 6]

obj.Artikel = obj.Artikel.filter(o => Object.keys(o).every(i => !blacklist.includes(+i.split(', ')[0].split(':')[1])))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic regex based on the `id` you want remove. Then, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to get all the objects which don't have any keys which have the given pattern

```js
const input={Artikel:[{"id:1, artikelnr":"23453345",anzahl:22},{"id:2, artikelnr":"asd323",anzahl:2223},{"id:5, artikelnr":"dfsdf3893",anzahl:72},{"id:6, artikelnr":"asdikr38",anzahl:86},{"id:9, artikelnr":"2sad34533asd45",anzahl:10}]},
    idToRemove = 6,
    regex = new RegExp(`id:${idToRemove}`),
    Artikel = input.Artikel.filter(o => !Object.keys(o).some(k => regex.test(k)))

console.log({ Artikel } )
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way to do it, would be:

```js
const j = {"Artikel":[
  { "id":1, "artikelnr": "23453345", "anzahl": 22},
  { "id":2, "artikelnr": "asd323", "anzahl": 2223},
  { "id":5, "artikelnr": "dfsdf3893", "anzahl": 72},
  { "id":6, "artikelnr": "asdikr38", "anzahl": 86},
  { "id":9, "artikelnr": "2sad34533asd45", "anzahl": 10}
]}


j["Artikel"].forEach(function(item, index){
 if(item["id"] == 6){
  j["Artikel"].splice(index, 1)
 }
});

console.log(j)
```